# Lattice iCEcube2, error synplify_pro 321

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, lattice

I just made a fresh install of iCEcube2, first time i'm using it, and whatever design files I use I've got this error when I try to synthetize :

```
/opt/iCEcube2.2017.01/synpbase/bin/synplify_pro: 321: 
/opt/iCEcube2.2017.01/synpbase/bin/config/execute: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ";;")
```

I'm using ubuntu 16. No idea what happens, and I don't know what I could do knowing that it's a fresh install. I tried to launch the software in sudo with same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

the issue here is that the "execute" script that iceCube2 is trying to run, is using as "shell" /bin/sh linked to /bin/dash, in Ubuntu, instead of /bin/bash.

the best workaround i found, is to **change the shell from /bin/sh to /bin/bash** in the first line of all the shell script in these directories..

/opt/iCEcube2.2017.01/synpbase/bin/
/opt/iCEcube2.2017.01/synpbase/bin/config/

Comment: Answering poorly received questions is kind of discouraged.  You should also take your time to capitalize properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrea Venturi for tip on the root cause. Indeed /bin/sh has very special meaming in Unix. For regular scripting /bin/bash should be used.
Here how to fix all iCEcube2 scripts:

```
$ cd <iCEcube2.2017.01>/synpbase/bin
$ find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\/sh/\/bash/g' {} \;
```